# Autoincrement empty array when pushing values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a text in a variable transformed in array string:

```
$text = 'Today is Monday';
$textTab = explode(" ",$text);
```

I have an empty array, declared as :

```
$tab[] = array();
$value = '';
```

I have few conditions and instructions :

```
foreach($textTab as $iter){
    if($iter == //something){
        array_push($tab,$value);
        $value = '';
    }else{
        $value = $iter;
    }
}
```

And when I try to var_dump the tab, after the for loop, $tab has only one entry.

Can someone explain my error ?

Comment: 1. Please make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code 2. What output do you get with `var_dump()` and what would you expect?

Comment: I'm sorry this is in French language. http://pastebin.com/M58hGNLe The var_dump returns me 'array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(17) "mardi 14 fevrier " }'. It takes only the first part of the sentence

Comment: @HugoTor what is end result that you're expecting?

Comment: @aharen If you've seen the pastebin, I would like to insert into the array the text separed by "et". For example, "Je suis Hugo et j'ai 19 ans". The array[0] = "Je suis Hugo" and array[1] = "j'ai 19 ans".

Comment: @HugoTor why not just `explode` with 'et' then, which would give you the result that you want eg: `$output = explode('et', "Je suis Hugo et j'ai 19 ans"); var_dump($output);`

Comment: @aharen Yes, it could be a solution, but I would to make other thing automatic, not only with the 'et' word separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, if you want the output `array(2) { [0]=> "Je suis Hugo " [1]=> " j'ai 19 ans" }` from the string "Je suis Hugo et j'ai 19 ans" you can simple explode at 'et'

```
$string = "Je suis Hugo et j'ai 19 ans";
$output = explode('et', $string);
var_dump($output);
```

To make it dynamic try

```
$splits = ['et', 'je'];
$string = "Je suis Hugo et j'ai 19 ans";
$string = strtolower($string);
$output = [];

foreach($splits as $split) {
    $outputTmp = explode($split , $string);
    $output[] = array_values(array_filter($outputTmp));

}
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: It works, but as I said in the comment above, I would like to make my function working for other words :/ Do you think that explode($word,$string) is possible ?

Comment: @HugoTor updated answer, you can define your splits points at `$splits` array like `$splits = ['et', 'je'];`

Comment: I don't really understand the function array_filter, even with the manual.. :/ But I think the whole code will work fine ! :)

Comment: I'm using `array_filter()` here to remove array items with empty values and since `array_filter()` preserve array keys `array_values()` is used to rest them :) Hope the code works for you, do let me know. Cheers :)

Comment: Just perfect ! :) Have to make a new algorithm, but THIS is the solution :) Ty !

Answer (score 1):

```
$tab[] = "asd"
```

is pushing the entry to the array, what you want is

```
$tab = array()
```

Comment: I think when you enable error-reporting you also get a warning that points to exactly that.

Comment: If I replace $tab[] = array() by $tab = array(), it just deletes the first index, but nothing else changes